# Nuxt SyntaxError: Unexpected token { at Object.Module._extensions..js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm getting this error whenever I run my application. Previously it's working.

[image: error]

I tried to remove node_modules/ and package-lock.json and re-run the npm install but I'm still getting the error.

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "vs_admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "Tech Dev",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=it nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate:it": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=it nuxt generate",
    "generate:staging": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=staging nuxt generate",
    "generate:uat": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=uat nuxt generate",
    "generate:production": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=production nuxt generate",
    "test": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=test nyc --reporter=lcov --reporter=text-lcov mocha --recursive --required mock-local-storage -r esm"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@johmun/vue-tags-input": "^2.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.14",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "config": "^3.0.1",
    "esm": "^3.2.5",
    "jodit-vue": "^1.2.4",
    "luxon": "^1.12.1",
    "mocha": "^6.0.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.4.3",
    "vue-affix": "^0.5.2",
    "vue-clamp": "^0.2.1",
    "vue-date-pick": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-datetime": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.17.0",
    "vuejs-noty": "^0.1.3",
    "vuelidate": "^0.7.4",
    "weekstart": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "mock-local-storage": "^1.1.8",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "nyc": "^13.2.0",
    "sass": "^1.17.4",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sinon": "^7.3.1"
  }
}
```

**nuxt-config.js**

```
const pkg = require("./package");

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  mode: "spa",
  head: {
    title: "Visit Singapore - Admin",
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      { hid: "description", name: "description", content: pkg.description }
    ],
    link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }]
  },
  router: {
    mode: 'history'
  },
  loading: { color: "#FF0000" },
  css: [
    "~/assets/css/main.scss",
    "~/assets/css/vueDatePick.css",
    "~/assets/css/input-tag.scss",
    "~/assets/css/input-tag.scss",
    "~/assets/css/vuejs-noty.scss",
    "~/assets/css/cards.scss",
    "~/assets/css/nprogress.css"
  ],
  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/vuelidate",
    "~/plugins/global-components",
    "~/plugins/vue-tags-input",
    "~/plugins/vue-clamp",
    "~/plugins/datepicker",
    "~/plugins/vue-draggable",
    "~/plugins/vue-noty",
    "~/plugins/vue-editor",
    "~/plugins/datetimepicker",
    "~/plugins/vue-affix"
  ],
  modules: ["bootstrap-vue/nuxt"],
  build: {
    transpile: ["vue-clamp", "resize-detector"],
    extend(config, ctx) { }
  }
};
```

Comment: What is you Node version?

Comment: @RafikFarhad v8.15.1

Comment: I upgraded my node version to 12.7.0 and nuxt version to 2.13.3 but still getting the error when I nuxt generate "generate:it": "NUXT_ENV_STAGE=it nuxt build && nuxt export",

Comment: I get the same using node v8.11.2 and nuxt 2.13.3

Comment: Did you clean after node version update? Did your NPM is updated?

Comment: I managed to fix it by updating my node version to 12.7.0

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when runnign node v8.10 on Ubuntu.
I updated node using: https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version

sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable

After i restarted my terminal i had node v12.
After that the problem was gone